# How to publish a module written in ES6 to NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was about to publish a module to NPM, when I thought about rewriting it in ES6, to both future-proof it, and learn ES6. I've used Babel to transpile to ES5, and run tests. But I'm not sure how to proceed:

1. Do I transpile, and publish the resulting /out folder to NPM?
2. Do I include the result folder in my Github repo?
3. Or do I maintain 2 repos, one with the ES6 code + gulp script for Github, and one with the transpiled results + tests for NPM?

In short: what steps do I need to take to publish a module written in ES6 to NPM, while still allowing people to browse/fork the original code?

Comment: I have been struggling with this decision lately.  I am seeing the answer you marked as correct by [José](http://stackoverflow.com/users/234047/jos%c3%a9-f-romaniello) being the consensus also.

Comment: Here's my [2018 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509974/1269037), taking into account the progress with module support since 2015.

Comment: I'd love if I could do the opposite. Use an ES Module to import an NPM module, but these are the only results I get.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The pattern I have seen so far is to keep the es6 files in a `src` directory and build your stuff in npm's prepublish to the `lib` directory.

You will need an .npmignore file, similar to .gitignore but ignoring `src` instead of `lib`.

Comment: Do you have example repository?

Comment: @JamesAkwuh Note that you will likely want to change the "start" and "build" commands in the package.json to use the relative path of the babel-cli: `./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js -s inline -d lib -w src`.

This should ensure that installs don't fail when deploying to new environments.

Comment: @phazonNinja npm handles it

Comment: “If there's no .npmignore file, but there is a .gitignore file, then npm will ignore the stuff matched by the .gitignore file.” [official npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers)

Comment: Instead of `.npmignore` you can use the [`files` field in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files). It lets you specify exactly the files you want to publish, instead of hunting for random files you *don't* want to publish.

Comment: I have a boilerplate repo that does exactly as what's mentioned in this answer and it's the recommended approach as well - [npm-module-boilerplate](https://github.com/flexdinesh/npm-module-boilerplate)

Answer (score 85):

I like José's answer. I've noticed several modules follow that pattern already. Here's how you can easily implement it with Babel6. I install `babel-cli` locally so the build doesn't break if I ever change my global babel version.

**.npmignore**

```
/src/
```

**.gitignore**

```
/lib/
/node_modules/
```

**Install Babel**

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "babel src --out-dir lib"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Any commands in the `scripts` will have `node_modules/.bin` added to their `$PATH` and since `babel-cli` installs a binary to `node_modules/.bin/babel` there is no need to reference the command by path.

Comment: Please notice that `prepublish` is problematic because it could run at install time (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3059), prefer the more idiomatic `version` script hook (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)

Comment: @mattecapu it seems like the problem with `prepublish` is still there. At the moment I think manually compile the `src` directory and `npm publish` is the way to go.

Comment: You can use `prepublishOnly` script hook (see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#prepublish-and-prepare). Note that in version 5 of npm this should function as expected, but for now (assuming you're using npm v4+) this should work.

Comment: @marius-craciunoiu, 
I still struggle, on which end the es5 transpilation is meant to happen? – [I can see loads of projects](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:github.com+prepublish:+node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js+src+--out-dir+lib), building (directly or indirectly through build target) in the `prepublish` script. But **nobody** (except for <1% I deem  in error) commits the `lib/` folder, as I can see from each respective repository... — thus `prepublish` is more of a syntax check, not  a pre-rendering (or: „pre-built binaries“) ?

Comment: How does `package.json - "files"` ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files)) interfere with `.npmignore`?

Comment: @FrankNocke from the docs, "even if they would be picked up by the files array", so "if in files and not in ignore", so you could, eg add `lib` to `files` and `*.doc.xml` to `.npmignore`.

Comment: @FrankNocke `prepublish` runs before `publish` (obv.), which pushes stuff to npm (or wherever you configure). So it's for building what goes in the NPM package, even if it's not checked in.

Comment: A good article (https://github.com/bookercodes/articles/blob/master/how-to-build-and-publish-es6-npm-modules-today-with-babel.md) suggests putting babel compilation into the `"build"` script, while executing it from `"prepublish": "npm run build"` or `"yarn build"` if your use `yarn` instead.

Comment: Note that the built-in `prepublish` script has been deprecated in favour of `prepare`. See here for an overview of the change: https://iamakulov.com/notes/npm-4-prepublish/

Answer (score 53):

**TL;DR** - Don't, until ~October 2019. The Node.js [Modules Team](https://github.com/nodejs/modules) has [asked](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/blob/master/doc/announcement.md#es-module-code-in-packages):

> Please do not publish any ES module packages intended for use by Node.js until [October 2019]

## 2019 May update

Since 2015 when this question was asked, JavaScript support for modules has matured significantly, and is hopefully going to be officially stable in October 2019. All other answers are now obsolete or overly complicated. Here is the current situation and best practice.

## ES6 support

99% of ES6 (aka 2015) has been supported by Node [since version 6](https://node.green/). The current version of Node is 12. All evergreen browsers support the vast majority of ES6 features. ECMAScript is now at [version 2019](http://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_overview.html#ecmascript-2019), and the versioning scheme now favors using years.

## ES Modules (aka ECMAScript modules) in browsers

[All evergreen browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) have been [supporting](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) `import`-ing ES6 modules since 2017. [Dynamic imports](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) are [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import) by Chrome (+ forks like Opera and Samsung Internet) and Safari. Firefox support is slated for the next version, 67.

You no longer *need* Webpack/rollup/Parcel etc. to load modules. They may be still useful for other purposes, but are not required to load your code. You can directly import URLs pointing to ES modules code.

## ES modules in Node

ES modules (`.mjs` files with `import`/`export`) have been supported since Node v8.5.0 by calling `node` with the `--experimental-modules` flag. Node v12, released in April 2019, rewrote the experimental modules support. The most visible change is that the file extension needs to be specified by default when importing:

```js
// lib.mjs 

export const hello = 'Hello world!';

// index.mjs:

import { hello } from './lib.mjs';
console.log(hello);
```

Note the mandatory `.mjs` extensions throughout. Run as:

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

The Node 12 release is also when the Modules Team [asked](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/blob/master/doc/announcement.md#es-module-code-in-packages) developers to not publish *ES module packages **intended for use by Node.js*** until a solution is found for using packages via both `require('pkg')` and `import 'pkg'`. You can still publish native ES modules intended for browsers.

## Ecosystem support of native ES modules

As of May 2019, ecosystem support for ES Modules is immature. For example, test frameworks like [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4842) and [Ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1810#issuecomment-491592951) don't support `--experimental-modules`. You need to use a transpiler, and must then decide between using the named import (`import { symbol }`) syntax (which won't work with most npm packages yet), and the default import syntax (`import Package from 'package'`), which does work, but [not when Babel parses it](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9938) for [packages authored in TypeScript](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9938#issuecomment-489371360) (graphql-tools, node-influx, faast etc.) There is however a workaround that works both with `--experimental-modules` and if Babel transpiles your code so you can test it with Jest/Ava/Mocha etc:

```js
import * as ApolloServerM from 'apollo-server'; const ApolloServer = ApolloServerM.default || ApolloServerM;
```

Arguably ugly, but this way you can write your own ES modules code with `import`/`export` and run it with `node --experimental-modules`, without transpilers. If you have dependencies that aren't ESM-ready yet, import them as above, and you'll be able to use test frameworks and other tooling via Babel.

---

Previous answer to the question - remember, don't do this until Node solves the require/import issue, hopefully around October 2019.

## Publishing ES6 modules to npm, with backwards compatibility

To publish an ES module to npmjs.org so that it can be imported directly, without Babel or other transpilers, simply point the `main` field in your `package.json` to the `.mjs` file, but omit the extension:

```
{
  "name": "mjs-example",
  "main": "index"
}
```

That's the only change. By omitting the extension, Node will look first for an mjs file if run with --experimental-modules. Otherwise it will fall back to the .js file, so your existing [transpilation process](https://github.com/dandv/local-iso-dt/blob/master/package.json#L11) to support older Node versions will work as before — just make sure to point Babel to the `.mjs` file(s).

Here's the [source for a native ES module with backwards compatibility for Node < 8.5.0](https://github.com/dandv/local-iso-dt) that I published to NPM. You can use it right now, without Babel or anything else.

Install the module:

```
npm install local-iso-dt
# or, yarn add local-iso-dt
```

Create a test file **test.mjs**:

```
import { localISOdt } from 'local-iso-dt/index.mjs';
console.log(localISOdt(), 'Starting job...');
```

Run node (v8.5.0+) with the --experimental-modules flag:

```
node --experimental-modules test.mjs
```

## TypeScript

If you develop in TypeScript, you can generate ES6 code and use ES6 modules:

```
tsc index.js --target es6 --modules es2015
```

Then, you need to rename `*.js` output to `.mjs`, a known [issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/436) that will hopefully get fixed soon so `tsc` can output `.mjs` files directly.

Comment: Saying "All evergreen browsers support the vast majority of ES6 features." doesn't mean much when you look at the [data](https://caniuse.com/#search=es6) and realise that es6 support in browsers only reaches about 80% of all users.

Comment: Currently, the ecosystem is definitely not mature enough for this. The Node.js team with the release of v12 specifically asked: "Please do not publish any ES module packages intended for use by Node.js until this is resolved." http://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html#es-modules-on-npm Mocha doesn't natively support .mjs files. Many-many libraries (e.g. create-react-app, react-apollo, graphql-js) had issues with dependencies containing `mjs` files. Node.js plans to roll out official support in October 2019 which is the earliest I would seriously revisit this.

Comment: "All other answers are now obsolete or overly complicated. Here is the current situation and best practice." This seems highly subjective and definitely does not reflect the state of npm packages being published in 2021.

Comment: For readers in 2022: This answer probably needs an update. In `package.json` one can set `"type": "module"` to read `.js` as `.mjs` by default. And maybe try to simplify it a bit, it's very verbose and misleading for me.

Answer (score 19):

@Jose is right. There's nothing wrong with publishing ES6/ES2015 to NPM but that may cause trouble, specially if the person using your package is using Webpack, for instance, because normally people ignore the `node_modules` folder while preprocessing with `babel` for performance reasons.

So, just use `gulp`, `grunt` or simply Node.js to build a `lib` folder that is ES5.

Here's my `build-lib.js` script, which I keep in `./tools/` (no `gulp`or `grunt` here):

```
var rimraf = require('rimraf-promise');
var colors = require('colors');
var exec = require('child-process-promise').exec;

console.log('building lib'.green);

rimraf('./lib')
    .then(function (error) {
        let babelCli = 'babel --optional es7.objectRestSpread ./src --out-dir ./lib';
        return exec(babelCli).fail(function (error) {
            console.log(colors.red(error))
        });
    }).then(() => console.log('lib built'.green));
```

Here's a last advice: You **need to add a .npmignore to your project**. If `npm publish` doesn't find this file, it will use `.gitignore` instead, which will cause you trouble because normally your `.gitignore` file will exclude `./lib` and include `./src`, which is exactly the opposite of what you want when you are publishing to NPM. The `.npmignore` file has basically the same syntax of `.gitignore` (AFAIK).

Comment: Instead of `.npmignore` you can use the [`files` field in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files). It lets you specify exactly the files you want to publish, instead of hunting for random files you *don't* want to publish.

Comment: Wont this break tree-shaking?

Comment: I don't recommend using `.npmignore`, try `package.json`'s `files` instead, see: https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/master/js/package.md#what-to-include

Comment: @thisismydesign: that's exactly what I had recommended in my comment above..?

Comment: My bad, didn't notice :)

Answer (score 12):

Following José and Marius's approach, (with update of Babel's latest version in 2019): Keep the latest JavaScript files in a src directory, and build with npm's `prepublish` script and output to the lib directory.

**.npmignore**

```
/src
```

**.gitignore**

```
/lib
/node_modules
```

**Install Babel** (version 7.5.5 in my case)

```
$ npm install @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "latest-js-to-npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Keep the latest JavaScript files in a src directory and build with npm's prepublish script and output to the lib directory.",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "babel src -d lib"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I have `src/index.js` which uses the arrow function:

```
"use strict";

let NewOneWithParameters = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a + b); // 30
};
NewOneWithParameters(10, 20);
```

Here is [the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/yucigou/latest-js-to-npm).

Now you can publish the package:

```
$ npm publish
...
> latest-js-to-npm@1.0.0 prepublish .
> babel src -d lib

Successfully compiled 1 file with Babel.
...
```

Before the package is published to npm, you will see that `lib/index.js` has been generated, which is transpiled to es5:

```
"use strict";

var NewOneWithParameters = function NewOneWithParameters(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b); // 30
};

NewOneWithParameters(10, 20);
```

**[Update for Rollup bundler]**

As asked by @kyw, how would you integrate Rollup bundler?

First, install `rollup` and `rollup-plugin-babel`

```
npm install -D rollup rollup-plugin-babel
```

Second, create `rollup.config.js` in the project root directory

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";

export default {
  input: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    file: "./lib/index.js",
    format: "cjs",
    name: "bundle"
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**"
    })
  ]
};
```

Lastly, update `prepublish` in `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "rollup -c"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now you can run `npm publish`, and before the package is published to npm, you will see that lib/index.js has been generated, which is transpiled to es5:

```
'use strict';

var NewOneWithParameters = function NewOneWithParameters(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b); // 30
};

NewOneWithParameters(10, 20);
```

Note: by the way, you no longer need `@babel/cli` if you are using the Rollup bundler. You can safely uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall @babel/cli
```

Comment: How would you integrate Rollup bundler?

Comment: @kyw, regarding how to integrate Rollup bundler, see my updated answer.

Comment: December 2019 update --> https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/71113bed90d275023664c97f3a869405d94bee0f/docs/07-tools.md#babel

Comment: Thanks for this! Just to clarify, to integrate your function in another project you can just use `import NewOneWithParameters from 'latest-js-to-npm';` ? So in your code you don't actually need `export`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to see this in action in a very simple small open source Node module then take a look at [nth-day](https://github.com/guyellis/nth-day) (which I started - also other contributors). Look in the package.json file and at the prepublish step which will lead you to where and how to do this. If you clone that module you can run it locally and use it as a template for yous.

Answer (score 6):

Node.js 13.2.0+ supports ESM without the experimental flag and there're a few options to publish hybrid (ESM and CommonJS) NPM packages (depending on the level of backward compatibility needed): https://2ality.com/2019/10/hybrid-npm-packages.html

I recommend going the full backward compatibility way to make the usage of your package easier. This could look as follows:

The hybrid package has the following files:

```
mypkg/
  package.json
  esm/
    entry.js
  commonjs/
    package.json
    entry.js
```

`mypkg/package.json`

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./commonjs/entry.js",
  "exports": {
    "./esm": "./esm/entry.js"
  },
  "module": "./esm/entry.js",
  ···
}

mypkg/commonjs/package.json

{
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

Importing from CommonJS:

```
const {x} = require('mypkg');
```

Importing from ESM:

```
import {x} from 'mypkg/esm';
```

We did an [investigation into ESM support in 05.2019](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/34415f7f9a4cedcc38f4faef1b0a9c66ee913b39/js/package.md#esm) and found that a lot of libraries were lacking support (hence the recommendation for backward compatibility):

- [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) package's support doesn't align with Node's which causes issues

  - "Builtin require cannot sideload .mjs files." https://github.com/standard-things/esm#loading, https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/498#issuecomment-403496745
  - "The .mjs file extension should not be the thing developers reach for if they want interop or ease of use. It's available since it's in --experimental-modules but since it's not fully baked I can't commit to any enhancements to it." https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/498#issuecomment-403655466
- [mocha doesn't have native support for `.mjs` files](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3006)

  - Update 2020-01-13: Mocha released experimental support in `mocha@7.0.0-esm1`
- Many high-profile projects had issues with `.mjs` files:

  - [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4085)
  - [react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1737)
  - [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1272)
  - [inferno](https://github.com/infernojs/inferno/issues/1296)

Comment: I can't seem to import globally installed ES6 modules in the node_modules folder (provided by npm root -g). Are we really not supposed to be able to do that? I am really confused. I know npm link can solve the problem by linking the module to my local node_modules folder, but I want to know why importing global node modules is not supported.

Comment: Answering myself, I guess it will never be supported: https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es-modules.md#432-removal-of-non-local-dependencies It's a really stupid decision though, would be easy to support...

Comment: @JoakimL.Christiansen Namaste. Having similar hardship due to the completely misarticulated official stance with regard to modules by the node community, I followed that link, and yes, I was disappointed, but not being satisfied, I checked the publish date of that linked article... 9 Aug 2017. Just pointing that out as the linked article could be a red herring so to speak...

Answer (score 4):

The main key in `package.json` decides the entry point to the package once it's published. So you can put your Babel's output wherever you want and just have to mention the right path in `main` key.

```
"main": "./lib/index.js",
```

Here's a well written article on how to publish an npm package

https://codeburst.io/publish-your-own-npm-package-ff918698d450

Here's a sample repo you can use for reference

https://github.com/flexdinesh/npm-module-boilerplate

Comment: That post omits the fact that you can (and should) [publish to NPM modules authored in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509974/1269037) and `import`able directly without requiring Babel or any other transpilers.

Answer (score 3):

The two criteria of an NPM package is that it is usable with nothing more than a `require( 'package' )` and does something software-ish.

If you fulfill those two requirements, you can do whatever you wish.
Even if the module is written in ES6, if the end user doesn't need to know that, I would transpile it for now to get maximum support.

However, if like [koa](http://koajs.com), your module requires compatibility with users using ES6 features, then perhaps the two package solution would be a better idea.

### Takeaway

1. Only publish as much code as you need to make `require( 'your-package' )` work.
2. Unless the between ES5 & 6 matters to the user, only publish 1 package. Transpile it if you must.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.  I think the OP is trying to figure out how to structure their Github repo and what to publish to NPM and all you've kind of said is that they can do whatever they want.  The OP wants specific recommendations on a good practice for this situation.

Comment: @jfriend00 I disagree. I've recommended that he transpile, and only publish the files that are required for `require( 'package' )` to work. I'll edit my answer to make this more clear. That said, Jose's answer is much better than my own.

Comment: José's answer is very good, but I appreciate this one for explicitly outlining good rules-of-thumb for when/why to use one vs. two packages.

Answer (score 0):

### A few extra notes for anyone, using *own* modules directly from github, not going through *published* modules:

The ([widely used](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:github.com+%22prepublish:+node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js+src+--out-dir+lib%22)) "prepublish" hook is not doing *anything* for you.

Best thing one can do (if plans to rely on github repos, not published stuff):

- unlist `src` from .npmignore (in other words: allow it). If you don't have an `.npmignore`, remember: A copy of `.gitignore` will be used instead in the installed location, as `ls node_modules/yourProject` will show you.
- make sure, `babel-cli` is a depenency in your module, not just a devDepenceny since you are indeed building on the consuming machine aka at the App developers computer, who is using your module
- do the build thing, in the [install hook](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) i.e.:

  `"install": "babel src -d lib -s"`

(no added value in trying anything "preinstall", i.e. babel-cli might be missing)

Comment: Compile on install is very rude. Please don't do this - npm install time is bad enough! For internal code where you want to avoid using an npm package repository, you can: 1) use a monorepo, 2) Upload and depend on `npm pack` output, 3) check in build output.

Answer (score 0):

Deppending on the anatomy of your module, this solution may not work, but if your module is **contained inside a single file, and has no dependencies** (does not make use of **import**), using the following pattern you can release your code as it is, and will be able to be imported with **import** (Browser ES6 Modules) and **require** (Node CommonJS Modules)

As a bonus, it will be suittable to be imported using a SCRIPT HTML Element.

**main.js** :

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    const myModule = {
        helloWorld : function(){ console.log('Hello World!' )} 
    };

    // if running in NODE export module using NODEJS syntax
    if(typeof module !== 'undefined') module.exports = myModule ;
    // if running in Browser, set as a global variable.
    else window.myModule = myModule ;
})()
```

**my-module.js** :

```
    // import main.js (it will declare your Object in the global scope)
    import './main.js';
    // get a copy of your module object reference
    let _myModule = window.myModule;
    // delete the the reference from the global object
    delete window.myModule;
    // export it!
    export {_myModule as myModule};
```

**package.json** :`

```
    {
        "name" : "my-module", // set module name
        "main": "main.js",  // set entry point
        /* ...other package.json stuff here */
    }
```

---

To use your module, you can now use the regular syntax ...

When imported in **NODE** ...

```
    let myModule = require('my-module');
    myModule.helloWorld();
    // outputs 'Hello World!'
```

When imported in **BROWSER** ...

```
    import {myModule} from './my-module.js';
    myModule.helloWorld();
    // outputs 'Hello World!'
```

Or even when included using an  **HTML Script Element**...

```html
<script src="./main.js"></script>
<script>
     myModule.helloWorld();
    // outputs 'Hello World!'
</script>
```