# What are some good practices to publish ES6 React modules to npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Few things that could help understand the process better

- Do we point the main in package.json to the transpiled bundled file?
  How do we make sure the react and other dependencies can be excluded from the bundle.
- Do we just import the parent component as the module?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [Releasing es6 and es5 sources with npm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31133915/1048572). Is it?