# Transpile React Native module to ES5 before publishing to npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

It was [suggested for a react-native plugin](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider/issues/22) that code on npm is best transpiled before publishing instead of relying on the end-developer to transpile.

Seems fine, but react-native users probably tend to have a very homogeneous babel-based setup, so perhaps it wouldn't be so problematic to just leave it in ES6. Fancy uses similar to [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) could be an exception where ES6 is rather inconvenient. But then sometimes I go digging in `node_modules` to see what's going on inside modules. Transpiled code would make that somewhat more difficult.

**Question is**: It seems like there's probably a most favorable, consistent answer. Is transpiling before publishing the right move? Am I inconveniencing people by performing this step?

**Question is not:** *how* to do this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738381/how-to-publish-a-module-written-in-es6-to-npm) addresses that very well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind yes, transpiling is a good step. We used it in [react-native-drawer-layout](https://github.com/iodine/react-native-drawer-layout), so we didn't have our users to enable certain babel features. On the other hand, the more Safaris JS engine reaches spec compliance with ES6, the more I would tend to say no, as transpiled code is almost always slower.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes - transpile now. Transpile for better compatibility with todays browsers. Re-transpile your package in the future (if you care), when more ES6 features will be supported by browsers - dropping some (now) transpiled code and going with portions of native ES6.