# Should I publish my module's source code on npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I hope this question won't be too opinionated, I'm asking about the best/common practice for this.

I'm publishing an npm module written in ES6 and transpiled to ES5 and UMD using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/).

The file structure could be summarized like this:

```
/coverage/
/dist/
/node_modules/
/src/
/test/
/tools/
.editorconfig
.eslintrc
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.travis.yml
CHANGELOG.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
LICENSE.txt
package.json
README.md
```

The source code is within `/src/` and the compiled code in `/dist/`.
These dirs are .gitignored:

- coverage
- dist
- node_modules

What the user would really use is indeed the content of `/dist/`.

I've been using a starter kit with a build process that:

1. takes the original `package.json`
2. removes all the scripts and dev related fields from it
3. copies it into dist
4. also copies the files LICENSE and README into dist (untouched)

The entire package source will be published on GitHub but I'm not sure about **what to publish on npm**:

**A)** the entire file structure (removing `/coverage/` and `/node_modules/`) with a top level `package.json` that has an entry point to the relevant file in `dist`

or

**B)** just publish the content of `dist` with a stripped down `package.json` and the README & LICENSE. I know that just publishing the content of `/dist` would render source maps useless.

What is the common practice here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738381/how-to-publish-a-module-written-in-es6-to-npm - Don't forget, modern bundlers support a [`module`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) field in `package.json` for raw ES6+ modules - for those consumers who don't need transpilation

Answer (score 20):

In my opinion, the best practice is to publish both minified code in `dist` folder and also the source code in `src` folder. One should also include other files such as `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `README.md`, `LICENSE.txt`, `CONTRIBUTING.md`, etc which are at the root package directory.

To achieve this, one should use **`files`** property in `package.json` to whitelist what needs to be published to `npm` instead of finding what is not required to be published by blacklisting in `.npmignore`.

The `dist` folder should have only minified bundle and no need to generate another `package.json` in dist folder by removing scripts, `devDependencies`, etc.

This is because when consumer of package do `npm install <package name>`, it installs only the packages inside `dependencies` and ignores packages under `devDependecies`.

The minified files can be used by browser by referring directly from scripts tag where load time will be smaller due to small file size while modern frameworks such as `angular` will use un-minified code. Modern frameworks have their own build tools, like `webpack`/`rollup` which create a minified bundle-file.

There is no need to have a top level `package.json` that has an entry point in the `main` field to the relevant file in `dist`. Instead, in my opinion, the top level `package.json` should have entry point to relevant file such as `index.js` at the same root package level.

Finally, one can run **`npm pack`** to see what is inside the tarball and then finally do `npm publish` to npm registry for public use from inside root package folder.

Comment: Anybody is aware of a good starter to publish npm packages in 2021?

Comment: I've been following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHQi5a0TmMc&t=58s

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to have a source code on npm, not the result of transpilation/minification/etc. It is also common to publish modules that don't need any transpilation in the first place.

If your module cannot be used in Node directly without transpilation (which would be very unusual for a module on npm and certainly not expected) then you either have to make sure that it is transpiled during installation (which is tricky and can corrupt user's file system if done wrong) or to include the `dist` in your published modules.

If you're going to include the `dist` in the published module then you need to make sure that the correct file is loaded when people require your module and that you always build a fresh `dist` before doing `npm version` and `npm publish`.

My advice, though, would be to write your Node modules in Node. That way they will be usable directly with small download, fast installation, no problems with transpilation and readable error messages - the last part is very important during debugging.

There is one serious problem with publishing transpiled code that is often overlooked. Publishing code that is different in any way than the actual source code, whether it is transpiled, minified or obfuscated in any way, has some security implications. It's very hard to audit transpilation results and you have to do that if that is the code that is actually being run (especially if you didn't transpile it yourself).

Comment: Not sure about this tbh. The creator of Babel [suggests to deploy](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2246#issuecomment-134420731) transpiled code

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Actually saying "Publishing uncompiled Babel code to npm is not a pattern that we want to encourage" is not exactly the same as suggesting to deploy transpiled code. But I was talking about publishing, not deployment, and I personally don't recommend publishing code that is different in any way than the actual source code, mostly for security reasons. It's very hard to audit transpilation results and you have to do that if that is the code that is actually being run - if you didn't transpile it yourself, which is the case when transpiled code is published on npm.

Comment: I see that point of view. But would you publish ES Modules, or CommonJS?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue npm is not only for Node so you can publish frontend code or anything else. I just don't recommend writing Node modules in a language that cannot be directly executed by Node.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your point. Transpiled code is still executed by Node (and frontend), it just allows for a wider audience since you don't have so say *You can only use Node v6+*. It can also produce full debug information via sourcemaps, so that point is definitely moot.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I'll put it this way: When I am doing a security audit of your module I have to audit the result and not the source of transpilation if that result is distributed on npm because someone could put a backdoor in the transpilation result manually after the transpilation. The source maps are irrelevant here. If you distribute the code before transpilation and you do the transpilation during the installation then this problem doesn't exist but other problems appear instead as I described in my answer. Either way there are problems and that is why I recommend avoiding them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142691/discussion-between-codingintrigue-and-rsp).

Comment: "... has some security implications" - This. There is **still** not remotely enough chatter about how dangerous it is that npm allows one to publish minified code. Either npm itself should automate building, minifying, etc. or it should require the user ultimately do it themselves (eg. the way that Rust's `cargo build` will download dependencies and compile them *from the actual source*, like many other languages)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think package should have only dist folder, package.json and ReadMe (and may be some config and scripts in [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) if necessary).

Reason not to include source files is that if anyone wants to look at source code, they can see it in source repo, mentioned in [repository](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#repository) section of your package.json. Why to pollute target package with source. Purpose of npm package is kind of "binary/exec/minimized" version of your lib, not source code and by this you save storage of users of your package.