# Publish a node module written in ES6 without providing the transpiled ES5 version b/c it is targeted for the latest browser

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs, browserify

My team will publish a node module written in ES6, targeted for the latest browsers.  All the ES6 features we use, like `async/await`, `import/export` are supported by our target browsers. So I believe providing the transpiled ES5 version does not make sense (Our targeted audiences assure us they will only use the latest Chrome).

But I found without the transpiled ES5 version when they use our module, they got `SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` even though their gulpfile already set

```
return browserify({ ... })
  .transform(babelify.configure({
    presets: ["es2015"]
  }))
  ...
```

If they just include our module source codes in their own codes they can `import` my module without any error. That makes me believe there should be some setting in my module so I can just provide ES6 version only.

BTW, I have read [How to publish a module written in ES6 to NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738381/how-to-publish-a-module-written-in-es6-to-npm)
and [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Wait what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029113/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-w/40029232)

They were not my question and the answers there didn't fix the `SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` my clients got.

Comment: So, are *you* having the issue with import/export syntax, or are the people trying to use your module having problems? Please post the code that causes the issues.

Comment: The latter. Man I thought I had made it clear in my question.

Comment: "*All the ES6 features we use are supported by our target browsers.*" - so why are you even using Babel?

Comment: B/C my client uses browserify to bundle all the js files into one big file. See my answer as well.

Comment: You might want to try out [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) which can bundle ES6 modules

Comment: After trying rollup for a whole afternoon, I gave up :(  For a simple task that webpack can handle without any problem, rollup just kept complained !] Error: 'foo' is not exported by ...   I tried everything said in https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module

Answer (score 1):

I spent a whole day solving it so I would like to share my experience.

First of all, it is browserify's parser that complained `SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` so what I need to do is to let the client's browserify transform my module and the solution turned to be quite simple!

[Why aren't files in node_modules being transformed?](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed)

> A possible solution is to add:
>
> {   "browserify": {
>       "transform": ["babelify"]   } } to the root of all your modules package.json that you want to be transformed.

So adding `"browserify": { "transform": [ "babelify" ] }` to my module's package.json and the the problem is solved!

It is easy to verify that, e.g. in my module's .babelrc I particularly set `"modules":false` (b/c [defaults to "commonjs"](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env/#modules))

```
{ "presets": [[
  "env",
  {
    "modules":false,
    "debug": true
  }
]]}
```

Then I got `SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` again!

PS,

I got more than one comments/answers said `<script type="module"`. Of course I knew script has type="module" but that is the wrong answer!

Because we are talking using node module in browser environment, type="module" can't solve the problem of import module from `node_modules`

Comment: Thanks for the self-answer.  I wonder if that is the only solution.

Comment: That is one of the reasons I post my answer here to see if someone else can come up with a better solution :)