# Why would we exclude node_modules when using babel-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Most of the question asking on the site is to how to exclude `node_modules` but instead, I'm wondering why would we want to exclude `node_modules`?

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Can anyone explain to me to the reason behind excluding `node_modules`?

Comment: Transpiling code is not cheap, and usually most npm modules are already runnable without transpiling. So having every file go to Babel is unncessary (and slow).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738381/how-to-publish-a-module-written-in-es6-to-npm/52509974#52509974

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In short, transpiling is an expensive process and many projects have thousands (if not hundreds of thousands) of lines of code imported in that babel would need to run over. Your `node_modules` should already be runnable without transpiling as said already and there are simple ways to exclude your `node_modules` but transpile any code that needs it. See https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171.

I have seen a lot of arguments back and forth about whether or not it should be the developer consuming the applications job of transpiling the library or the library developer's responsibility. Most of the time transpiling is done for browser support and the library creator has no knowledge of what browsers you need to support so they end up either transpiling or not transpiling leaving it in your hands. If they transpile to ES5 you are golden, if not it is usually a simple enough task to figure out which libraries are causing issues and transpile them yourself

Comment: "Your node_modules should already be runnable without transpiling" - as stated in the subsequent paragraph, this isn't necessarily true, as depending on which browsers are being targeted there may well be a need to transpile imported modules and/or add polyfills.

Comment: I meant to say more that developers should be doing their due diligence and transpiling for you to something like ES5 but that isn't always the case. I don't think I was very clear on this point. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: would there be issues if we transpile it anyway ?
In my case, when using webpack and babel loader, If i transpile node_modules, some of the usage is breaking

Comment: how will we know when we need to transpile a module from node_modules/ if its a legacy app? Go through and read all the package.json dependency docs? or is there a static parser I can run my webpack entry object through I wonder