# Npm ES Module package do not work with Express / Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

First, all the code are available on [this repository](https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/stackoverflow-test-es6-module) to easily try it. (and the package is published into npm so can be used as test)

I'm trying to make this simple NPM ESModule package works backwards with Nodejs CommonJS + babel.

---

**The package** (`1-npm-package` on the Github repo)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-es6-module-npm-package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Text NPM package ESModule",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "author": "ArthyFiciel"
}
```

src/index.js

```
export const sayHello = (name) => {
  console.log(`[Npm module package]: Hello ${name}`);
};
```

Ps: This package is published to npm and can be used with `npm i test-es6-module-npm-package` and `import { sayHello } from 'test-es6-module-npm-package'`

---

**THE ERROR** (`4-commonjs-express-with-babel-and-esm` on the Github repo)

This project is a simple Express server using Babel.

[**package.json**](https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/stackoverflow-test-es6-module/blob/master/4-commonjs-express-with-babel-and-esm/package.json) (Only put a link in order to avoid big files)

**src/index,js**

```
import express from 'express';

import { sayHello } from 'test-es6-module-npm-package'; // <<< THIS CAUSING ERROR

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7000;
const app = express();

app.listen(PORT, async () => {
  sayHello(`I'm server on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

But when I try to run it I got an error:

```
/test-es6-module/4-commonjs-express-with-babel-and-esm/node_modules/test-es6-module-npm-package/src/index.js:1
export const sayHello = (name) => {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arthyficiel/Dev/GrilledCode/StackOverflow/test-es6-module/4-commonjs-express-with-babel-and-esm/dist/index.js:11:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
```

---

The GitHub project also provide 2 others tests:

- [`2-express`](https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/stackoverflow-test-es6-module/tree/master/3-commonjs-express-with-babel) An ESModule express server who prove the package is working.
- [`3-commonjs-express-with-babel`](https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/stackoverflow-test-es6-module/tree/master/3-commonjs-express-with-babel) The exact same projects (`4-commonjs-express-with-babel-and-esm`) without any reference to my package, working fine.

**Node version** v12.14.0

**NPM version** v6.13.4

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after lots of research I found that Babel do **not** bundle your dependencies with your project. 
So a CommonJS project cannot implement a pure-ESM package (but should use a wrapper package who just transpile the ESM package to a CommonJS).

The best solution (Package side) I found is to publish an Hybrid Package:

- Developing the package:

  - as ESM (using `type:"module"` on root `package.json`)
  - into a `src/`
- Add Babel in order to create a CommonJS version (into a `./lib` directory)

  - then run transpile script on `publishOnly` npm script
  - and not forget to add a `{type:"commonjs"}` on `./lib` (I did it with `echo \"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"}\" > ./lib/package.json` at the end of prepublishOnly)
- Specify both version (EsM and CJS) on Root package.json:

  - `"main":"lib/index.js"`  // CommonJS version
  - `"exports":"./src/index.js"`  // Default ESM version

**Github:** I added this answer (and more examples) on the repo: [npm-package-with-cjs-support](https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/stackoverflow-test-es6-module/tree/master/1-npm-package-with-cjs-support)

**Note:** I'm still looking for a solution on the root-project side instead of package side. Maybe a way to find all pure esm and bundle them together?

#### More Links

- https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html
- https://github.com/nodejs/modules/#features
- https://2ality.com/2019/10/hybrid-npm-packages.html
- [How to publish a module written in ES6 to NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738381/how-to-publish-a-module-written-in-es6-to-npm)
- https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-js-12-from-experimental-to-release/